# Hired to be Fired?

Tags: termination

Since day 1 in this company, I felt something was wrong.

Maybe I am not the only one who felt this, since some manager spent a week only and left.

Anyway, the problem I am facing is that I was assigned two tasks related to two technologies I don't have any idea about. Instead of hiring specially skilled people on this area, they chose to convert developers with technical potential to work on these.

They didn't provide any training, and they prioritised a task (the easy one) over another of, and suddenly, without prior notice, they interrupted some meetings and rushed me to start producing in this technology I know nothing of.

Naturally, I responded that I can't do much and it's going to be a total failure. they shouldn't throw responsibility on a subordinate in such a chaotic way.

The escalation reached management, and all they did is to give me phone calls and tell me "talk to person 1, so that they talk to person 2, so that they talk to person 3, just try, just do whatever you can do ...".

Since the beginning of this new job in this project, I kind of foresaw this outcome, but I didn't really have a choice, and I wasn't sure yet, so I dove in.

All I can this of right now is that whether they secure the contract with the client or not, they will fire me, and that's how it felt.

My gut tells me that it's too much for mismanagement - they can't fail that way unless it's on purpose.

Am I wrong?

Comment: "*No one in this world, so far as I know ... has ever lost money by underestimating the intelligence of the great masses of the plain people*" But even the most incompetent of managers, with perhaps one notable exception, don't spend time hiring people just to fire them so do you have a more practically answerable question?

Comment: "*Naturally, I responded that I can't do much and it's going to be a total failure.*" - naturally. 

Comment: Downvote because "Am I wrong?" is not really a question that can be answered by strangers on the internet. This reads as more of a rant than a question.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your post a bit, but may it be that your behavior has signalized the management that you are unwilling to do the job, expect that things will not work out anyway, and assume that they are incompetent? And that is why they want to get rid of you now? Did you deliver the impression that you are working hard on a very difficult job, or instead that you don't try too hard because you knew it was pointless from the beginning?

Comment: @Nebr, a manager came to me and told that top management consider you the best element they rely on you. I did a good job at some point, I made things move forward, and impressed the client, but my contribution dropped since a certain event. Without too much details, the event was that I had already too much responsibilities, I was started to focus when they came to me to give me more job that is not part of what I signed up for in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Have they hired you to fire you?  Unfortunately, we can't answer that as we aren't mind readers and can't know what your employers are thinking.

Do they appear from your description to be a completely dysfunctional organisation with no capacity to manage or hire effectively?  Undoubtedly.

What should you do?  I'm sorry but that's something you have to decide for yourself.  But it doesn't sound like a good place to be for long, it would be wise to start polishing your CV again and give yourself options.

Answer (score 3):

They did not hire you just to fire you. Hiring costs time and money as does firing. What may have occurred is that they found a better candidate and they only had a budget for one. This has been known to occur in the electronics design industry. It is plausible that you were on the face of it OK for the job and at the time the best that they could get on the salary cap. Then somebody really excellent appeared.